# C# Catch value of duplicate key from NpgSqlException

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I know that when Postgres raises a duplicate key exception, it usually gives the value of the duplicate element in the detail of the exception itself.

```
    ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "name_of_pkey"
    DETAIL:  Key (field_name)=(value) already exists.
```

From C#, how can i get that value from a NpgSqlException (NpgSql 3.1.7.0) now that the field Details has been removed from the exception class?

Comment: if its not giving then check whether it contains key before adding

Comment: thank you, i noticed the comment too late, though. this would have led me quicker than i did to the solution

Comment: Did it help you? So that I can put in answer. could you please accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [3.1 migration notes](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/migration.html), in Npgsql 3.1 PostgreSQL errors are thrown as PostgresException, which extends NpgsqlException. NpgsqlExceptin is thrown for various client-side errors (e.g. networking).

You'll find the Detail property on PostgresException.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Shame on me, i didn't search for migration notes!

Comment: Thank you! Link structure changed, [here is the new one](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/release-notes/3.1.html) (for version 3.1).
For later releases use [this link](https://www.npgsql.org/doc) and select the version of interest on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, while at some point Detail was accessibile directly from the NpgSqlException as a parameter of the class itself, i can now access the detail as a KeyValuePair in the Data property of the Exception class, this way:

```
exception.Data["Detail"]
```